# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[AnyHashable : Any]?' and 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, compiler-errors

I would like to show an alert when I have the error but I don't know how to print the error. I think that I have to use "info" but I don't know how. It shows me this error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[AnyHashable : Any]?' and 'String'

```
extension PHAsset {

   func getAssetThumbnail(asset: PHAsset, sizeW: CGFloat, sizeH: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let retinaSquare = CGSize(width: sizeW, height: sizeH)

    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var thumbnail = UIImage()

    options.isSynchronous = true
    options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    options.resizeMode = .exact
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: retinaSquare, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
        thumbnail = result!

        if info == PHImageErrorKey {

        }

    })
    return thumbnail
 }
```

}

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9hxL.png

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error clearly states `info` is a dictionary. You have to check if the dictionary *contains* the error key

```
if let error = info[PHImageErrorKey] as? String {
    print(error)
    // show an alert
} else {
   thumbnail = result!
}
```